# how to use spring data jpa to return a new result with native sql join query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Employee and Department entity and I want to return a EmpDeptDto result after executing a join query and below codes are for your reference.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "dept_id")
    private Long deptId;
}
```

and this is my Department entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}
```

here is my EmpDeptDto class.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmpDeptDto {
    private String empDept;
    private String empName;
    private String empEmail;
    private String empAddress;
}
```

this is my repository

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.example.join.dto.EmpDeptDto (d.name as empDept, e.name as empName, e.email as empEmail, "
            + "e.address as empAddress) "
            + "FROM department d LEFT JOIN employee e ON d.id = e.dept_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<EmpDeptDto> fetchEmpDeptDataJoin();
```

and I am sure that the dto class path is correct but when i execute it, the application return that `SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000` and `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.example.join.dto.DeptEmpDto(d.name as empDept, e.name as empName, e.email as em' at line 1`

I struggled with this problem almost one day, can someone helpme?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try without `nativeQuery = true`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `nativeQuery` here because you're using JQPL query, not native.

Try like this:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.join.dto.EmpDeptDto(d.name, e.name, e.email, e.address) " +
        "FROM Department d " +
        "LEFT JOIN Employee e ON d.id = e.deptId")
List<EmpDeptDto> getEmpDeptDto();
```

Updated my answer, since I confused with dto name. It should be ok now

Comment: Hi kerbermeister,
yes, it works!! But if I want to use native query?  Where should I edit my codes?
Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use nativeQuery, you should write a regular native SQL query (not JPQL) and specify nativeQuery = true. But since you're using DTO here, it’s important to point out that class-based projections do not work with native queries AT ALL. You can use interface-based projections instead. Read reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections